# pig UDF using external java libraries

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I wrote UDF that uses some external libraries as jackson-databird etc...how can I specify where should pig looks for these external libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if you compile all your dependencies to a single fat jar?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the additional Jars using the syntax -

pig -Dpig.additional.jars="xxx.jar:yyy.jar" -f script.pig

having a jar with dependencies might cause problems incase the packaged dependencies and the cluster installed dependencies are not compatible. This will also make your program future proof, i would assume.